# Rewrite Non-www to www and HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, dns

I have both the following simultaneous requirements:

- http to https
- non-www to www

To deal with the first requirement, I have the following Apache config section:

```
ServerName www.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/elbcheck.html https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

The `X-Forwarded-Proto` condition works with my AWS load balancer, and the `RewriteRule` is intended to avoid re-write when dealing with the `elbcheck.html` file only, as it is the target of the AWS load balancer's health check. This is tested and working ([source](https://blog.qruizelabs.com/2014/06/06/ssl-aws-elb/)).

But, I'm having a hard time consistently getting non-www to route to www. I came close at one point, but ran into a major issue with https://example.com re-writing to https://www.example.com

How do I keep things working with my http to https re-writes but also fix my non-www to www re-writes?

Comment: Change the ELB check to TCP Protocol to port 80 in health check. And then apply those rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is multi-pronged. First, I found a very useful answer over on ServerFault:

https://serverfault.com/a/728957/336268

Using this, I rewrote my Apache config as follows. Note that it still preserves my `elbcheck.html` avoidance requirement.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule !/elbcheck.html https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !/elbcheck.html https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Immediately after doing this and re-starting Apache, I noticed the redirect starting to work from the problematic https://example.com

But, a new problem emerged. The browser started complaining that the security certificate was not valid. A little more research and I lucked out in finding this article:

http://www.jasonsamuel.com/2011/03/07/how-to-properly-use-ssl-redirects-without-getting-certificate-error-messages/

The article basically says that the problematic redirect https://example.com cannot be solved by configration alone and requires reciprocal support at the certificate level. My wildcard certificate didn't cover the "apex domain" case and thus resulted in the browser complaining about the certificate's validity with the case in point.

Fortunately, for me, since I use Amazon Web Services, fixing the certificate problem was a snap. I just requested a new certificate from ACM that included both the apex and the wildcard. I installed the certificate on my AWS load balancer, and my problem is now resolved.

Comment: I also want to comment that a big part of my issue in the first place was not being able to read and understand Apache mod_rewrite. It's incredibly complicated, especially when you also need to read and understand Regular Expressions syntax. I found the following to be useful in getting me proficient enough to be able to help to get my config working: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/elbcheck\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I like where you're going with that, but when restarting Apache I'm getting a syntax error on the last line `RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters apache config test fails, aborting`

Comment: Sorry I skip one line. I have updated my answer. It will resolve your query.

Comment: Syntax OK, but now `http://www.example.com` rewrites to `http://www.www.example.com`. That's bad. Still, thanks for helping!